# JavaFX Platform.RunLater() takes much longer than Java Thread, but Thread is causing a massive error

Tags: java, user-interface, multithreading

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void setData(ModPackage modPackage) throws MalformedURLException {
        modOwnerLabel.setText("by " + modPackage.getOwner());
        modNameLabel.setText(modPackage.getName());

        
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String iconURL = modPackage.getVersions().get(0).getIcon();
                Image iconImage = new Image(modPackage.getVersions().get(0).getIcon());
                packageImage.setImage(iconImage);
            }
        });
        myThread.start();


    }
```

Where `modPackage.getVersions()` returns an arrayList, `modPackage.getVersions().get(0).getIcon()` returns a single String which is a URL to a .png icon on the internet, `iconImage` gets that image and `packageImage` is an ImageView inside of an HBox which is inside of an AnchorPane.

So the method takes the `modPackage` Object, gets the icon from one item in `modPackage`'s class variable ArrayList of versions, downloads that image from the internet, and adds the image to an ImageView Node.

This method is called about eighty times in one click of a button.

This method is called from here:

```
PackageItem packageItem;
AnchorPane itemAnchorPane;
    for(int i = startNum; i < finalEndNum; i++){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/packageItem.fxml"));

        itemAnchorPane = fxmlLoader.load();

        packageItem = fxmlLoader.getController();
        packageItem.setData(modPackages.get(i)); <-

        packageBox.getChildren().add(itemAnchorPane);
    }
```

Where `finalEndNum - startNum = 80` each time the method that this for loop is in is called (user clicks a page number and calls the method containing this for loop). So in essence this for loop is creating a new instance of a `PackageItem` node (picture a rectangle about 50x500px with an image and some text), adding data to the node's children (ImageView and Labels) and adding the node to a VBox. It does this eighty times. So in calling the `setData` method I am creating eighty new threads(?).

So here's the issue:

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090082/how-to-fix-indexoutofbounds-exception-when-javafx-recomputes-parent-node-bounds) that using Java Threads when dealing with UI is a big no no. I get the exact error that the linked post is talking about. But using Platform.RunLater makes this execute either a lot slower or more probably just a lot later, in either case when the user presses a page number there is a blank screen for almost 15 seconds. Not sure where to go from here. I don't know if there's just a better way to get the images or what, but it would likely take just as much time, no?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I do not use FXML, but I wonder if you really need to instantiate a new `FXMLLoader` inside each loop.

Comment: Refer to [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: @BasilBourque true I don't think I need to do that. Thanks.